# Filter data from two content types with different criteria in view

Tags: nodes, views

I've got these two content types, A and B. It's pretty straightforward to set up and display them in the same view. However, I can't get them filtered. I've added two filters rules, one for each content types, a1 and b1 respectively, in the hope that I can extract the right parts of the data from A and B and show them in my view. But that doesn't work out.

//
a1=published *and* content type A *and* category=aa
b1=published *and* content type B *and* tag=bb
//

Here is what I got while trying to do so:

1. no rules at all,
   view displays all the stuff from A and B
2. rule a1,
   view displays A only
3. rule b1,
   view displays B only
4. rule a1 or b1,
   shows nothing

   [filter groups i used](http://s12.postimg.org/3ys44nsf1/filter_rules.png)

Is there anything wrong or filter criteria can only be applied?
Any help is appreciated.

--update 1--
I did some more experiments about grouping filter criteria:

```
 - case 1
Content: Published (Yes)  AND  
Content: Type (= Portfolio)  
OR  
Content: Published (Yes)  AND  
Content: Type (= Blog entry)  AND  
Content: Tags (= frontpage) | Settings   
 - case 2
Content: Published (Yes)  AND  
Content: Type (= Portfolio)  
Content: Tags (= frontpage) | Settings   
OR  
Content: Published (Yes)  AND  
Content: Type (= Blog entry)  AND
```

"Content: Tags" is a unique field which only appears in content type "Blog entry" . To my surprise, case 1 and 2 will yield the same result, blog entries, even though "Content: Tags" has nothing to do with the content type "portfolio".

--update 2--
a bug?
[Incorrect filter group OR behavior](http://drupal.org/node/1766338)

Answer (score 2):

a1 and b1 will show nothing, because `content type == A AND content type == B` is always false for 'A != B'

On filter block, you have a drop down with options. You need to group them into groups connected with OR, so you will have:

```
published and ( (content type == A and category == aa) or (content type == B and tag == bb ) )
```

Comment: Hi Mołot， I did use "or" instead of "and", please find the link of screenshot I just added to the original question which displays my filter groups setting. Thanks

Comment: Looks OK, and that's a bad news. It means I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show parts (you must mean fields) of your two content types just do the following:

1. Add a filter of Content type checking the two content types A & B
2. At the Format/Show section click on content and on that window choose fields.
3. Then go the Fields section and start adding fields that belong to those types.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already managed to show the fields in view. It is the individual filter criteria that confused me.

Comment: No problem. Glad you solved your problem.

Comment: Actually the problem is still there, I can't filter the right nodes to be shown in my view. I've add some update to the original question. THX

Comment: case 1 seems correct. are you sure you have created nodes of protfolio type?

Comment: yes, I can see them if I use "content type" as the only filters.

Comment: Then maybe you are forgetting to add fields from portfolio type. I think there's no other explanation.